# google_conversion_id = null

Tags: php, javascript, google-ads-api

I am using a simple Php if condition to make the Adwords google snippet visible if the user is redirected to his profile after a successful registration

```
<?php if( $_GET['getVariable']=='String' ) { ?>
// google adwords snippet ( copy/pasted
<?php } ?>
```

this condition is deployed inside the Html body.

If the GET variable is sent, the snippet become correctly visualized inside the Html, however upon inspection with firebug the DOM var google_conversion_id and google_conversion_label are both set but equal to NULL.

Is that because of the dynamically generated HTML/JavaScript code?

Any advice is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Is that because of the dynamically generated HTML/JavaScript code?

No. Your Server-side code generates the HTML/JS before-hand, and so on the client-side it will load in the browser as normal.

The issue is not because your code is dynamic, but there must be an issue elsewhere that you've not yet accounted for.